# Return Google Image Search Results in HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, image, api

I know how we can use the Google API to return image results in AJAX, but I want to be able to return images for a specific query and then output them in to HTML on  my page.

For example:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=sausages

Returns results with infomation and images about the top 10 results for the keyword sausages.

How can I query this url to output the images and titles of the images on my page using PHP in HTML.

I am using the following at the top of the function to return the title:

```
$tit = get_the_title();
```

Then I am apending it here:

```
$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q='.$tit.'');
```

But it won't recognize the title

Comment: This returns a JSON string. Paste it here and you will see the result: http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm Read about JSON.

Comment: That title abbreviation of yours is partially what contributed to my up-vote.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function get_url_contents($url) {
    $crl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=sausages');

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
    $results[] = array('url' => $result->url, 'alt' => $result->title);
}

print_r($results);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Salchicha_oaxaque%25C3%25B1a.png/220px-Salchicha_oaxaque%25C3%25B1a.png
            [alt] => Sausage - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Reunion_sausages_dsc07796.jpg
            [alt] => File:Reunion sausages dsc07796.jpg - Wikimedia Commons
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zDyoLPoM1Zg/ULXDPba_2iI/AAAAAAAAAAs/QzfNNmDFmzc/s1600/shop_sausages.jpg
            [alt] => Maik's Yummy German Sausage
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://sparseuropeansausage.com/images/sausage-web/sausagesBiggrilling2.jpg
            [alt] => Spar's European Sausage Shop
        )

)
```

**Showing the images:**

```
<?php foreach($results as $image): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"/><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

**Edit after comments:**

```
$url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=' . get_the_title(); 

$json = get_url_contents($url);
```

Comment: Hi Enenen, Thanks, ok that works, but how could I output it plain html without all the array details. So just the image url and the title, in plain text?

Comment: Ok, well at the monet it prionts all the array information like: [0] => Array, I just want to be able to print the url and the title.

Comment: Then in the loop (`foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result)`) you can just use `echo '<img src="' . $result->url . '" alt="' . $result->alt . '"/><br/>';` without storing the information in an array.

Comment: Last question... I'm using this in wordpress and have added: $tit = get_the_title(); to the top of the code. I'm then appending that to the end of the query using .$tit. but it's not working, any ideas?

Comment: This is what I'm using and it's not recognizing it

Comment: Now I get this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/movies/public_html/wp-content/themes/moviestv/single.php on line 123

Comment: @AlanCarr did you fix it! cause i'm having the same problem and don't know what wrong .. wired so please if you fixed it, share it.

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted that this API is no longer available from Google, and will always return an error code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should be posting this as a comment to enenen's answer. Unfortunately I don't have the reputation to be able to do so at the moment.

Enenen's answer worked really well, I however came across some images that refused to load correctly for me. It might be obvious to others, but it took me a while to figure it out.

Some of the returned URLs have encoded characters that weren't picked up properly by the browser and resulted in a broken image. This was only every 1 in 50 images or so.

The string returned was for example:
http://pix4.agoda.net/hotelimages/106/10615/10615_14033018230018907115.jpg%3Fs%3D800x600

Solved this by using the PHP function urldecode on $image['url']

```
$img_url=urldecode($image['url']);
echo '<img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$image['alt'].'">';
```

New string that is working properly in my browser (%3F and %3D decoded)
http://pix4.agoda.net/hotelimages/106/10615/10615_14033018230018907115.jpg?s=800x600

Answer (score 0):

***Forget About Google and get the same images URL's using Bing.com***

Example searches work fine on my [website](http://ogena.net).

You can give this function a try:

The function returns an array of images found. You can opt out more for your custom parameters.

```
function searchImage($search){

$url="http://www.bing.com/images/search?pq=".urlencode(strtolower($search))."&count=50&q=".urlencode($search);
$data=file_get_contents($url);

$rr=explode("<div class=\"item\">", $data);
$execc="";
for($r=2;$r<(count($rr));$r++){
    $nf=explode("\"", $rr[$r]);
    $nextFile=$nf[1];
    $no="stock;123;dreams";
    $x=true;
    $tt=explode(";", $no);
    for($a=0;$a<count($tt);$a++){

            if(strpos($nextFile, $tt[$a])!=false){
                    $x=false;
            }
    }
    if($x==true){
            $nextFil[]=$nextFile;
    }
}
return $nextFil;
}
```

Comment: It returns value "thumb"