# how to make a image search engine?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to make a image search. it will be showing images of movies and i also want the movie name to show below the image. this is what i got far

In my phpMy i got 5 rows

id  int(11)

title   varchar(100)

description text

url text

keywords    varchar(100)

Here is my search bar

```
<div>
<form action='/search.php' method='GET' style="margin-bottom:1px;">
<input id='searchbar' type='text' size='65' name='search' placeholder="search for movies & tv shows">
<input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' >
</form>
</div>
```

and this is the results page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FastMegaMedia</title>
<link rel="icon" href="img/putlockermedia_logo.png" type="image/icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/index.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

<?php include_once("/php/header.php"); ?>


        <table id=content width="100%" height="25" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

              <?php include_once("/php/ad1.php"); ?>

              <td width="63%" valign="top">
               <section class="content"> <!-- start of conntent -->
               <?php
$x = 0;
$construct = '';  

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
else
{
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("search");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM  searchengine WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br><li> 
Try more general words. for example: If you want to search 'how to create a website'
then use general keyword like 'create' 'website'</li><li> Try different words with similar
 meaning</li><li> make sure you are spelling is correct</li>";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$title = $runrows ['title'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$url = $runrows ['url'];

echo "
<a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br>
$desc<br>
<a href='$url'></a><p>
";

}
}

}
}

?>

</section> <!-- end of conntent -->
              </td>

              <?php include_once("/php/ad2.php"); ?>

           </table>



</body>
</html>
```

what could I do to make it show images instead of just showing the tittle, i know i'm missing something.. i'm new to this btw be nice

Comment: id you Outlining your code, its better readable

Answer (score 0):

First, you appear to be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) attacks. Never trust unsanitized user-input data.

Well, you need to store the image somewhere (I'd store it on disk with the path/file name stored in the database as type varchar), then in your PHP code where you output the title, description, and URL, just also query the database for the image path and `<img src...` that.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the images and the references to them (if they exists in your database):

```
echo "
<a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br>
$desc<br>
<a href='$url'></a><br>
<img class='images' src='$srcOfFoundImage' title='$titleOfFoundImage'><p>
";
```

If you dont have the images, you [can ask Google to find them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16855957/669677).