# Search image duplicate with google images

Tags: php, image, google-image-search

Google images has possibility to look for an image using other's image url.
I want to use it to look for a image duplicate on my social website.
Does someone have php script that does that? Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855957/return-google-image-search-results-in-html-using-php May help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has great plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm?hl=pl That will do it.